# In TestCafe, there is a way to get a list of all test cases of a project filtering by metadata

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need the information of an specific set of tests before running them. Can be all available tests, of some tests with a certain parameter in metadata.
Something like:
[Test xxx] - Perform actions......
[Test xxx] - Something ....

Environment details:
testcafe version: 1.8.1
node.js version: 10.16.1

Comment: Exactly what point in the life-cycle of the test or set of tests do you want to see this information? Should it appear immediately before a specific test is run, or can it appear sooner (before the actual tests start to run)?

Comment: I need it before test execution. What I need is all the information about tests available.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is output data from the [`filter` method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#filter), which provides pretty much any information about the test (before running) that you can get.

At that point, you can use that information to only run specific tests, or `return true` to not filter anything and only use the `filter` method for printing information.